# Unity3D with Visual Studio 2019 - Auto Refresh

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

This feels like a slightly off topic question but have asked on.. Unity Answers, Unity Forum, Super User and MS Visual Studio Support and not got a reply anywhere, so hoping with the amount of developers here someone might have come across this and have an answer.

Is there a setting I'm missing for a project in Visual Studio to auto refresh/reload when adding a new C# file from the Unity3D Editor?

With the previous bundled version of Visual Studio that came with the Unity3D Editor it would do this but after upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 I have to manually "reload" the project from within Visual Studio which undoes any unsaved changes.

Thanks.

Comment: click RMB on project in "project viewer" and select "Set autoload project". It solve problem for me.

Not sure if it works for you.

Here is similar issue discussion link : 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/visual-studio-doesnt-reload-project-after-scripts-are-added-within-unity.587617/

Comment: @Shweta Thanks, not sure where you meant by "project viewer", but have found a solution now thanks. Will post an answer incase anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I installed Visual Studio 2019 the Unity Tools Extension wasn't an optional add-on.

Since then it has become one and adding that using the Visual Studio Installer to modify the existing installation and then setting the "Automatic project reloading" option within the Unity tools Extension to `true` fixed the issue.

Solution Steps.

**Step 1:** Open the Visual Studio Installer and select ***Modify***

[image: Fix Step 1]

**Step 2:** Scroll down to the ***Game development with Unity*** extension.

[image: Fix Step 2]

**Step 3:** Once the extension is installed open the option window (**Tools -> Options**)

Then find the **Tools for Unity** tab and set ***Automatic project reloading*** to `true`

[image: Fix Step 3]

**Step 4:** Restart Visual Studio

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this and is unable to find any answers as was the case with me.

Answer (score 1):

Not precisely related as Auto Reload isnt the same as Auto Refresh Asset Databsae, but google brought me here, so this may help others.  I found that if you have auto refresh turned off using Unity->Edit->Preferences->Asset Pipeline->auto refresh->disabled, the Visual Studio 2022 setting "Refresh Unity's AssetDatabase on Save" overrides this and still forces an auto refresh.  If you're working a lot in Visual Studio making changes, saving etc, you can end up with incredibly long refresh times on my machine Unity 2021.3.24f1 seeing up to 50 minutes of recompiling scripts messages, but that never seems to happen when you manually refresh when ready.  Hopefully this helps someone trying to turn off autorefresh but not seeing it function properly.